# 0x800a0e7c - ADODB.Parameters: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I want to execute sql queries with parameters in classic asp. To do so I am using ADODB COMMAND object and an array of parameters, which I'm looping through and binding one parameter at a time to ADODB COMMAND object. See my below code:

```
 PRIVATE FUNCTION MapParametersToCommand(dbCmd, arrayParameters)
    FOR EACH parameter IN arrayParameters
        dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter(, GetDataType(parameter), 1, , parameter)            
    NEXT    
END FUNCTION
```

"GetDataType" is a method that is returning datatype and it's working fine. Over all method is working fine but in a particular scenario getting below exception:

> 0x800a0e7c - ADODB.Parameters: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

In above code when we loop over array of parameters, when the parameter value is "%" it throws above exception. I've even tried to add extra single quotes ("'%'") but still getting the same exception. In this case datatype is coming as string (ie. 129 in number and correct as well) and value is "%" (tried with "'%'" ).

I found many similar question in which people got same error but the reasons were different than my case.

Things That I tried:
1. Added reference of adovbs.inc
2. Passing correct datatype
3. In debugger control goes to GetDataType method and comes back and then getting exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a value for the **Size** argument

From the doc for [CreateParameter Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> If you specify a variable-length data type in the Type argument, you must either pass a Size argument or set the Size property of the Parameter object before appending it to the Parameters collection; otherwise, an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks Morpheus, after passing size in case of STRING datatype it start working.